# A different captcha approach

Tags: security, drag-and-drop, captcha, spam-prevention

Reformatted into a question....

---

**Is drag and drop a good catcha method?  I.e. would it be a good way of allowing only humans to submit a form?**

---

Original text:

> You can start voting down but i am a
>   newbie and here is my captcha version!
>
> The captcha will be based on drag and
>   drop...
>
> a human being could implement drag and
>   drop. A bot?
>
> Just a thought!

Comment: Hi - it's already been done :)

Comment: @AdaTheDev Didn't know about this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment, it's already been done, one example [here](http://www.webdesignbeach.com/beachbar/ajax-fancy-captcha-jquery-plugin) :)

Comment: This is actually a pretty good idea, and solution - given it stops unwanted bots. Seemed strange however that in the demo I could see if the correct image was dropped based on the icon displayed in the drop location (only one image was accepted?). Anything is better that trying to enter long CAPTCHA 'phrases' like sometimes required here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Drag and drop what? The thing here is not the behavior. A computer can drag and drop programmatically. The issue here is things computers cannot do, or do well. For instance, recent ideas have suggested orienting images right-side up. Like a dog upside down needing to be flipped vertically, or a stop sign needing to be oriented 45 degrees clock-wise. More complicated images would be children hanging upside down on monkey-bars, etc.

Drag-and-drop won't cut it alone. What will you be dragging, and where will you be dropping it ;)

Comment: I understand that it is about behaviour but the drag & drop couldn't be combined with the mouse move?

Comment: Gipap, drag-and-drop isn't a mouse moving around at the code-level.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue to address is how a drag and drop system would work if the user has JavaScript disabled. (You'd need to fallback to *something* and that something would also need to be hard to fake.)

Then again, HTML5 *might* resolve this issue as long as you don't need mainstream browser support any time this century.

Answer (score 0):

Any javascript-based CAPTCHA will do (no need to do fancy stuff like drag and drop). The only problem is accessibility and support for browsers without decent javascript (hello IE Mobile?)

Answer (score 0):

> Is drag and drop a good catcha method? I.e. would it be a good way of allowing only humans to submit a form?

This is nice idea in correct direction. 
One should prevent passing captcha to 3d party human solvers sweatshops (which do not directly interact with web-boards being cracked)

But the mentioned

- http://www.webdesignbeach.com/beachbar/ajax-fancy-captcha-jquery-plugin

is 100% passable by bots in 5 guessing, while bots have 15-20 before being locked.
The spambot devs I asked about it just called it "a masqueraded trap".

I am making survey of spam and anti-spam techniques and would recommend to look into [KeyCAPTCHA](https://www.keycaptcha.com/?changelang=en) plugin. 
See my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484477/how-to-protect-html-form-from-spammers/4495250#4495250) on it for more details.